# Spring framework context.getBean does not return a singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

for first sorry for my english.

I've got a Web Application in Spring and a Singleton Bean marked as @Component that return two different hashCode (so not the same object) if It is injected into a Controller (where It is autowired) and If I get It with context.getBean("mybeanname") into a Runnable class.

That Bean is simply annotated with @Component and is not marked as Prototype.
That thing occurs also with others Stateless Bean like a @Service Bean.

When I call context.getBean the Application Context return me a NON singleton object.

Why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code of your bean: If the bean retains state, which is used to calculate `hashCode` it is well possible that subsequent calls of the same bean result in different hashCode values. It is also possible, that you could have different application contexts.

Comment: it is very unclear! Could you please consider including some code & rephrasing your question?

Comment: At the moment I could not post the code but Yes It's a stateful Bean that I use too keep "in memory" data.
Another important thing I forgot to say is that It's a modular Application where the I have a Web Context with: Controller, JSP etc with its own Application context and a Business Layer where I have all Models, Service Component and that Stateful singleton Bean.